# Htaccess 410 error for url ending in *gions*

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my .htaccess file now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} gions [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,NC,L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^promotii.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/rochii-mireasa/promotii/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^colectia.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/rochii-de-mireasa/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^material.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/rochii-de-mireasa/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^stil.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/rochii-de-mireasa/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^decolteu.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/rochii-de-mireasa/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)gions$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

I want the following scenario: every url that ends in **gions** should have a 410 error page. It does not work now no matter what I do, even if it is the first rule. Only the last rule is matched that redirects to index.php.

What can I do to change this and have 410 page for every url that ends in **gions**?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a `RedirectMatch` directive:

```
RedirectMatch 410 ^.*gions$
```